# Some projects cannot be imported because their project description file is corrupted

Tags: java, eclipse, importerror, sap-commerce-cloud, eclipse-project-file

Was trying to import my SAP Hybris projects into Eclipse Workspace via
**Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace**.
But as soon as I give the path of my custom folder to import my Eclipse gives the error **Some projects cannot be imported because their project description file is corrupted**.
And the same files are working perfectly fine for my other teammates.

[ErrorOfScreenshotWhileImporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9zeR.png)

Tried creating a new workspace and importing projects again, but nothing helped.

Also, here is the snippet of the error I can see in the workspace .metadata/log directory.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 567 2022-06-30 21:08:52.444
!MESSAGE Failure occurred reading .project file.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 567 2022-06-30 21:08:52.445
!MESSAGE The element type "buildSpec" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</buildSpec>".
!STACK 0
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 3; The element type "buildSpec" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</buildSpec>".
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1465)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1695)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2899)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescriptionReader.read(ProjectDescriptionReader.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescriptionReader.read(ProjectDescriptionReader.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.loadProjectDescription(Workspace.java:1991)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardProjectsImportPage$ProjectRecord.setProjectName(WizardProjectsImportPage.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardProjectsImportPage$ProjectRecord.<init>(WizardProjectsImportPage.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardProjectsImportPage.lambda$7(WizardProjectsImportPage.java:979)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the files are corrupted, the files are corrupted. what do you expect us to do about that?

Comment: for the other teammates the same files are working perfectly fine

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail. Show us the `.project` file for one of the failing projects.

Answer (score 1):

Here  .project file was missing the ending tag:

```html
</buildSpec>
```

Adding the tag to the .project file of the corrupted project resolved my issue.